# ie6 looking for missing dll's when using Java Applet

Tags: java, applet, internet-explorer-6

I have a problem when I use the applet tag within Internet Explorer 6.
Here is the code I use:

```
<APPLET 
    height=1024 
    archive=consignation-applet-signed.jar,httpclient-4.0.1.jar,httpcore-4.0.1.jar,commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,log4j-1.2.14.jar 
    width=1280   
    code=PilotageImpression.class>
<PARAM NAME="_cx" VALUE="33867">
<PARAM NAME="_cy" VALUE="27093">
</APPLET>
```

The problem is that it tries to reach two URL's on Microsoft's website. It's a problem when you are in a closed environment.

I read an article here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323207/en-us but it says that the problem is only known when using the OBJECT tag (I use Applet tag)

Does anyone know why does this occur with the applet tag?

Comment: OK. I'll do my best to avoid this mistake next time I post.

Answer (score 0):

If your user has the Next Generation Plug-In (Sun's 1.6.0_10+), it would be easy to deploy this applet along with it's natives, using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

JWS could also launch the applet with natives on versions prior to the next generation plug-in, but they would be free-floating, outside the browser.

Comment: Why is the free floating applet 'impossible'?

Comment: I noticed that the problem is coming from DeployJava.js which is a part of Sun's Deployment Toolkit. When I call the applet without it, I haven't the same behavior.

Comment: 1) Update your question to include the JS used to call the script. 2) I did not mention deployJava.js, are you trying to launch the applet or JWS configured applet using it?